# How to perform a haptic feedback on dialog?

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialog

I want to perform a haptic feedback when the user press an item on the dialog.
I can't use the method of view:

```
view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
```

because I don't hold view in my hand (only Activity)

What can I do?

Comment: How about getting a `DecorView` of the dialog and calling `performHapticFeedback` on it? `dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY)`

Answer (score 2):

You can write you own class that extends Dialog and/or DialogFragment.

And add in the buttons callbacks (or wherever you want to perform a vibration)

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(250);
```

You will also need to add the permission `android.permission.VIBRATE` in your manifest.

In order to only vibrate if the user has not disabled haptic feedback in the general settings of his phone, you can get his choice with :

```
Settings.System.getInt(Context.getContentResolver(),                                    
                       Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);
```

Comment: please note that you have to add `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission to the `AndroidManifest` in this case

Comment: true :-) ; added to the answer for clarity

Comment: It will works but I want to use haptic feedback only when the user enable haptic feedback and not force him.